# C used to build web server

Tags: c, http

I am trying to build a web server in C that will dump request messages to the console. I got it working earlier today but now my program can't seem to connect to a server. I can create a socket just fine but the connect function returns -1. Why would that happen now and not a few hours ago? Any insight would be appreciated.

```
//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");

//Send some data
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

//Receive a reply from the server
if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("recv failed");
}
puts("Reply received\n");
puts(server_reply);

return 0;
```

Comment: When the connection error happens, try to use `perror()`, instead of `printf()` or `puts()` to get more error information.

Comment: it says connection was refused. why would it be refused?

Comment: According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html).  `ECONNREFUSED  No-one listening on the remote address.`  So you may want to check your code on the server side.

Comment: Try `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` (terminal command) to see if anyone can connect.  Once this is fixed, turn back to your own code and make it connect too.

Comment: telnet says the connection was refused. am i able to fix it?

Comment: How are you running the web server?

Comment: Or try connecting to IP `93.184.216.119` where we know a functional web server is listening on port 80.

Comment: i connected to 93.184.216.119 just fine. but am i able to fix the localhost connection somehow?

Comment: We cannot possibly tell, given only the information we have from you.  I suggest you ask a new question where you explain how you've tried to set up the server on the localhost.

Comment: Why don't you go back to the code that was working earlier?  Oh, you mean you aren't using a version control system (VCS)?  That was careless.  Using one saves you're bacon in situations like this, as long as you do actually check-in early and often.

Comment: @user2383049 Try to simplified your sever code down to it is only waiting to be connected and try your client code again to see if it works. Then add the code back to see what is causing the problem.  If the simplified code still does not work, you can edit your question and post your code here. So others can take look at it.